# Looping a basic jquery animation causes "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: jquery

I have the following simple jQuery animation to create a sort of loading bar for my visitors:

```
    function animate() {
    $("#box").animate({width:"1000px"}, function() {
        $("#box").animate({left:"1000px"}, function() {
            $("#box").css('width', '100px');
            $("#box").css('left', '-110px');
        }); 
    });

    $("#box2").delay(500).animate({width:"1000px"}, function() {
        $("#box2").animate({left:"1000px"}, function() {
            $("#box2").css('width', '100px');
            $("#box2").css('left', '-110px');       
        }); 
    });
    animate();
    }
```

However whenever I run it with the last `animate();` function for it loop again, I get this error:

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Why is this the case and how do I get the above animation to loop properly?

Thanks

Comment: you already got a nice answer from @tushar but just for suggestion - it would be better to avoid such ambiguous function names - try giving it name like `animateBox()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling your function  `animate();` inside your function so it's a infinite loop and very fast so Memory is filled `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

call this function outside your function like below:-

```
function animate() {
    $("#box").animate({
        width: "1000px"
    }, function () {
        $("#box").animate({
            left: "1000px"
        }, function () {
            $("#box").css('width', '100px');
            $("#box").css('left', '-110px');
        });
    });

    $("#box2").delay(500).animate({
        width: "1000px"
    }, function () {
        $("#box2").animate({
            left: "1000px"
        }, function () {
            $("#box2").css('width', '100px');
            $("#box2").css('left', '-110px');
        });
    });
}
animate();
```

if you want to call it multiple times `setInterval`

```
setInterval(animate,2000);
```